# Can not download files from a Virtual Machine

Tags: scp, gcloud

I run a google cloud virtual machine instance. I have some MySQL backup files to be downloaded to my local computer. I run Ubuntu 14.10 LTS and I have configured Xfce as GUI. I tried to email it via Gmail and google drive, but files are not uploaded. When I tried to use gcloud SCP command as follows but failed. Where is the error?

```
D:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK>gcloud compute scp src api-project-316008881718:/home/buddhika_ari/backups/latest/dinulaka_2017-09-05_06h38m.Tuesday.sql.gz des d:

ERROR: (gcloud.compute.scp) Multiple remote sources not supported by PuTTY.  Got sources: [src, api-project-316008881718:/home/buddhika_ari/backups/latest/dinulaka_2017-09-05_06h38m.Tuesday.sql.gz, des], destination: d:
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to add `src` and `dest` in your command, those are just placeholders. Following command should work:

```
gcloud compute scp api-project-316008881718:/home/buddhika_ari/backups/latest/dinulaka_2017-09-05_06h38m.Tuesday.sql.gz d:
```

Comment: ERROR: (gcloud.compute.scp) Could not fetch resource: - The resource 'projects/apl-project-316008881718/zones/asta-southeastl-b/lnstances/api-project-316008881718' was not found

Comment: Have you checked if the name of your compute instance is correct via `gcloud compute instances list`? Maybe there's a typo in the name...

Comment: No. Double checked.